# OpenAL and location-based sound source

Tags: java, android, audio, geolocation, openal

I'm trying to develop a location-based android app which used 3d sound library, openAL. Specifically, i have follow the instructions from [this tutorial](http://pielot.org/2011/11/10/openal4android-2/)  and now I'm trying to place a sound source somewhere in the map, and have the listener move around with his phone in hand, and 'feel' where the sound is coming from. Any help or turotial to implement this?

--------------****** RESOLVED******--------

I follow the instructions of [this very helpful implementation](https://github.com/wainach/Pervasive-Project/tree/master/Android)